# Issue in view.py : message error Invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I've created the following structure for my Django app:

```
../programs/  #home page for the app 
../program/id #detailed page about a specific program stored in the db
```

However, when I try to access from the browser ../programs/1 (with 1 being the id of the program I want to see details about) I get the following error:

```
ValueError at /programs/1/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1/'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/programs/1/
Django Version: 1.10.7
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1/'
```

Here is my code:

views.py

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Step, Cycle, Program, MotorSetting, GeneralSetting
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

def index(request):
   all_programs = Program.objects.all()
   context = {
       'all_programs': all_programs
   }
   return render(request, 'programs/index.html', context)


def program(request, program_id):
    try:
        program = Program.objects.filter(id=program_id).get()
        return render(request, 'programs/program.html', {'program': 
        program})
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("A program with this ID does not exist yet.")
```

program.html

```
{{ program }}
```

programs.urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #frontend homepage
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    #single program page
    url(r'^(?P<program_id>[0-9]+/)$', views.program, name='program'),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

class Program(models.Model):
    program_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    program_description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    cycles = models.ManyToManyField(Cycle)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.program_name
```

I can't seem to spot the error, hope that someone of you can help. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern `url(r'^(?P<program_id>[0-9]+/)$', views.program, name='program'),` in your `urls.py` captures the `/` in the `program_id` group. Move it out of the group like so:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #frontend homepage
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    #single program page
    url(r'^(?P<program_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.program, name='program'),
                                 ^ here
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the position of  '/' from the url regex ,

Change

```
url(r'^(?P<program_id>[0-9]+/)$', views.program, name='program'),
```

to,

```
url(r'^(?P<program_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.program, name='program'),
```